# Twilio nodejs helper library - Can't send SMS/Voice call using IP instead of Domain Name

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Recently, we have faced an issue with our Domain server going down. We are not sure what is the problem with it but due to this sending SMS and making voice calls in our Nodejs application is failing. We thought of making a call using IP instead of using suggested approaches for [SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/node/programmable-sms) and [Voice call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-node-js#going-further-with-nodejs-mmses-and-smses) by Twilio. Can you please suggest an approach to use IP instead of Twilio Domain Name in making Twilio calls.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your best bet might be to ask the customer service for their advice.

Comment: Is your problem that you want Twilio to send webhooks to your IP address rather than your domain name? Or are you asking whether you can use the IP address behind `api.twilio.com` instead of the domain to make requests to the Twilio API?

Comment: My question is whether we can use the IP address behind api.twilio.com instead of the domain to make requests to the Twilio API